# Andoid Ionic cordova @ionic-native/camera error doesnt fix

Tags: android, node.js, angular, gradle, ionic-framework

When I run > npm install @ionic-native/camera
I have allways this error :

## npm audit report

ansi-regex  >2.1.1 <5.0.1
Severity: moderate
Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in chalk/ansi-regex - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-93q8-gq69-wqmw
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/@ionic/angular-toolkit/node_modules/cliui/node_modules/ansi-regex
node_modules/@ionic/angular-toolkit/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/string-width/node_modules/ansi-regex
node_modules/@ionic/angular-toolkit/node_modules/wrap-ansi/node_modules/ansi-regex
strip-ansi  4.0.0 - 5.2.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of ansi-regex
node_modules/@ionic/angular-toolkit/node_modules/cliui/node_modules/strip-ansi
node_modules/@ionic/angular-toolkit/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/string-width/node_modules/strip-ansi
node_modules/@ionic/angular-toolkit/node_modules/wrap-ansi/node_modules/strip-ansi
cliui  4.0.0 - 5.0.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of strip-ansi
Depends on vulnerable versions of wrap-ansi
node_modules/@ionic/angular-toolkit/node_modules/cliui
yargs  10.1.0 - 15.0.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of cliui
Depends on vulnerable versions of string-width
node_modules/@ionic/angular-toolkit/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/yargs
webpack-dev-server  2.0.0-beta - 4.7.2
Depends on vulnerable versions of chokidar
Depends on vulnerable versions of selfsigned
Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
node_modules/@ionic/angular-toolkit/node_modules/webpack-dev-server
@angular-devkit/build-angular  <=13.0.0-rc.3
Depends on vulnerable versions of @angular-devkit/build-webpack
Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
node_modules/@ionic/angular-toolkit/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
@ionic/angular-toolkit  1.0.0 || 3.0.0 - 3.1.1 || 5.0.1-beta.0 - 5.0.3
Depends on vulnerable versions of @angular-devkit/build-angular
node_modules/@ionic/angular-toolkit
@angular-devkit/build-webpack  <=0.1300.0-rc.3
Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
node_modules/@ionic/angular-toolkit/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-webpack
string-width  2.1.0 - 4.1.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of strip-ansi
node_modules/@ionic/angular-toolkit/node_modules/cliui/node_modules/string-width
node_modules/@ionic/angular-toolkit/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/string-width
node_modules/@ionic/angular-toolkit/node_modules/wrap-ansi/node_modules/string-width
wrap-ansi  3.0.0 - 6.1.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of string-width
Depends on vulnerable versions of strip-ansi
node_modules/@ionic/angular-toolkit/node_modules/wrap-ansi

glob-parent  <5.1.2
Severity: high
Regular expression denial of service - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-ww39-953v-wcq6
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/@ionic/angular-toolkit/node_modules/glob-parent
chokidar  1.0.0-rc1 - 2.1.8
Depends on vulnerable versions of glob-parent
node_modules/@ionic/angular-toolkit/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar
webpack-dev-server  2.0.0-beta - 4.7.2
Depends on vulnerable versions of chokidar
Depends on vulnerable versions of selfsigned
Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
node_modules/@ionic/angular-toolkit/node_modules/webpack-dev-server
@angular-devkit/build-angular  <=13.0.0-rc.3
Depends on vulnerable versions of @angular-devkit/build-webpack
Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
node_modules/@ionic/angular-toolkit/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
@ionic/angular-toolkit  1.0.0 || 3.0.0 - 3.1.1 || 5.0.1-beta.0 - 5.0.3
Depends on vulnerable versions of @angular-devkit/build-angular
node_modules/@ionic/angular-toolkit
@angular-devkit/build-webpack  <=0.1300.0-rc.3
Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
node_modules/@ionic/angular-toolkit/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-webpack

node-forge  <1.0.0
Severity: moderate
Open Redirect in node-forge - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-8fr3-hfg3-gpgp
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/node-forge
selfsigned  1.1.1 - 1.10.14
Depends on vulnerable versions of node-forge
node_modules/selfsigned
webpack-dev-server  2.0.0-beta - 4.7.2
Depends on vulnerable versions of chokidar
Depends on vulnerable versions of selfsigned
Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
node_modules/@ionic/angular-toolkit/node_modules/webpack-dev-server
@angular-devkit/build-angular  <=13.0.0-rc.3
Depends on vulnerable versions of @angular-devkit/build-webpack
Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
node_modules/@ionic/angular-toolkit/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
@ionic/angular-toolkit  1.0.0 || 3.0.0 - 3.1.1 || 5.0.1-beta.0 - 5.0.3
Depends on vulnerable versions of @angular-devkit/build-angular
node_modules/@ionic/angular-toolkit
@angular-devkit/build-webpack  <=0.1300.0-rc.3
Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
node_modules/@ionic/angular-toolkit/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-webpack

14 vulnerabilities (8 moderate, 6 high)

To address all issues, run:
npm audit fix

even if i do :> npm audit fix --force it doesnt work, and the application run but nothing in the screen

Comment: this is the code : https://github.com/OmarBENOTMANE/app3.git

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem months ago. I couldn't fix it after like 3 weeks of trying and had to update the entire project to Capacitor and use @capacitor-community/camera-preview. It wasn't easy at all. It was a pain but managed to get it done. Maybe the community made some updates and will work faster than 6 months ago. I wish you all the best of luck!

Comment: Thank you Andrei I will try with Capacitor and yeah I've been trying for a whole week.

Comment: Maybe it's fixable.. But I couldn't :)) Anyway, it's a good thing to upgrade to Capacitor